# Finding most similar items by euclidean and cosine

Tags: r, similarity, knn, euclidean-distance, cosine-similarity

How do I go about finding similarities in R? In particular, the similarity metrics I care most about are cosine and a KNN-# value. I guess the key aspect of this is so that the data comes out in a usable shape for me.

For example using the built in mtcars dataset, I would want to find the most similar items.

```
 library(tidyverse)
mtcars$item = rownames(mtcars)
mtcars = mtcars %>% select(item, mpg, hp, qsec) # use these 3 fields to find similar items.
  #help <here>

#desired format would be have the <N> most similar items in <N> columns indicating their respective importance
# desired format would also have the weightings of each of these items
mtcars$similar_1 = #most similar item
mtcars$similar_1_score = #.8
...
mtcars$similar_5 = #5th most similar item
mtcars$similar_5_score = #score associated with them.
```

I'd like to be able to do this again with a KNN approach using Euclidean distance and then a separate cosine score.

Comment: Also, you say "most similar item," but do not reference the input values (features) for which you would like to produce this similarity. Do you want to use all of these?

Comment: @Imo - added the package to take care of this.  Additionally, yes, I want to use the 3 numerical columns I have in teh select statement.

Comment: Ah, missed the second part in the code comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solituin, where you're using the `dist()` function for calculating the Eucledian distances. First, you calculate the distances for all items, then get the order for all items. From that order you pick the ith one and select that score and item label for each item and put that in a data frame, which you bind to your original one after.

```
    mtcars$item = rownames(mtcars)
    data <- (mtcars %>% select(item, mpg, hp, qsec))[1:10,]

    euc_dist <- as.matrix(dist(data[1:10,-1]))

    # Get the ith cars label name for one car
    ith_item <- function(col, euc_dist, top_i) {
      labels(euc_dist)[[1]][top_i[col]]
    }

    # Get the ith cars score from one column
    ith_score <- function(col, euc_dist, top_i) {
      euc_dist[top_i[col], col]
    }

    # Create a dataframe with the ith most similar item for all items
    ith_similar <- function(euc_dist, i) {
      orders <- apply(euc_dist, 2, order)
      top_i <- orders[i + 1, ]

      top_i_score <- sapply(1:ncol(euc_dist), ith_score, euc_dist, top_i)
      top_i_items <- sapply(1:ncol(euc_dist), ith_item, euc_dist, top_i)

      similarities <- data.frame(placeholder1 = top_i_score,
                                 placeholder2 = top_i_items)

      colnames <- c(paste0("similar_", i, "_score"), paste0("similar_", i))
      names(similarities) <- colnames

      similarities
    }

    # For example top 2 similarities
    n <- 2

    for(i in 1:n) {
      tmp_similarities <- ith_similar(euc_dist, i)

      data <- cbind(data, tmp_similarities)
    }

    data
```

This will give the output of:

```
                           item  mpg  hp  qsec similar_1_score         similar_1 similar_2_score      similar_2
Mazda RX4                 Mazda RX4 21.0 110 16.46        0.560000     Mazda RX4 Wag        3.006726 Hornet 4 Drive
Mazda RX4 Wag         Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0 110 17.02        0.560000         Mazda RX4        2.452835 Hornet 4 Drive
Datsun 710               Datsun 710 22.8  93 18.61        4.733297          Merc 230       12.987767        Valiant
Hornet 4 Drive       Hornet 4 Drive 21.4 110 19.44        2.452835     Mazda RX4 Wag        3.006726      Mazda RX4
Hornet Sportabout Hornet Sportabout 18.7 175 17.02       52.018155          Merc 280       65.040680  Mazda RX4 Wag
Valiant                     Valiant 18.1 105 20.22        6.041391    Hornet 4 Drive        6.606815  Mazda RX4 Wag
Duster 360               Duster 360 14.3 245 15.84       70.148075 Hornet Sportabout      122.123141       Merc 280
Merc 240D                 Merc 240D 24.4  62 20.00       31.072369        Datsun 710       33.165796       Merc 230
Merc 230                   Merc 230 22.8  95 22.90        4.733297        Datsun 710       11.369802        Valiant
Merc 280                   Merc 280 19.2 123 18.30       13.186296     Mazda RX4 Wag       13.234032 Hornet 4 Drive
```